# Как отправить картинку и текст одним сообщением?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать такую отправку сообщения? Вопрос не в том, как тегать юзера, а как отправлять картинку и текст одним сообщением через discord.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При отправке сообщения, помимо аргумента `content`, передайте также аргумент `file`:

```py
await ctx.send('Тест', file=discord.File('test.png'))
```

Здесь `test.png` - название изображения